# asynchronous client socket closing?

Tags: sockets, asynchronous, client

hey i want to ask a question about asynchronous socket communication on c#. everything is working well for now apart from closing clients. server doesnot close immediately the worker socket for client when a client close its conneciton. it closes a few time later. how can i resolve this problem??

Answer (score 2):

check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx#2 my problem is that I can't keep the connection open after I receive a message from the client. 
If I do as said on that sample the connection is closed immediately after receiving the message. 
If I don't close the connection I can only receive one message and nothing more.
If you have any solution to this throw it this way.

I got it!

If anybody else has this problem they should do the following.
Change this code:

```
content = state.sb.ToString()
```

to this:

```
 content = state.sb.ToString().TrimEnd(New Char() {ChrW(13)})
```

then you should change this:

```
 If content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1 Then
```

to this:

```
If content.IndexOf(New Char() {ChrW(13)}) > -1 Then
```

this will receive Enter (chrw(13)) as the end of line.

then here:

```
Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from socket. " + vbLf + " Data : {1}", content.Length, content)
' Echo the data back to the client.
Send(handler, content)
```

you should do this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from socket. " + vbLf + " Data : {1}", content.Length, mid(content,1,content.length -2))
' Echo the data back to the client.
'Send(handler, content)
 content = String.Empty
 state.sb.Clear()
 handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf ReadCallback), state)
```

And your done.